# Segmentation fault in C++ using vectors

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm having trouble with a segmentation fault caused by the following line:

```
heapVec[currentsize] = *(new Node(d));
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Node {
private:
    int data;
public:
    Node(int);
    // ~Node();
};

class Heap {
private:
    vector<Node> heapVec;
    int currentsize;
public:
    Heap();
    // ~Heap();
    void insert(int);
    void extractMin();
    void reduceKey();
};

Node::Node(int d) {
    data = d;
}

void Heap::insert(int d) {
    heapVec[currentsize] = *(new Node(d));
    currentsize++;
}

Heap::Heap() {
    // this is the default constructor
    currentsize = 0;
}

int main() {
    Heap *h = new Heap;
    h->insert(10);
}
```

Comment: The code `*(new Node(d))` is completly wrong. It allocate object of  class Node, and forgot about the pointer. It's a definition of memory leak. You must change` vector<Node> heapVec;` to `vector<Node*> heapVec;` or use something like `boost::ptr_vector<Node> heapVec;`.

Comment: Don't use a vector<Node*>. You will most likely end up with a memory leak, because you will have to manually delete every vector member.
Just do, what Dani said below, and you're fine.

Comment: +1 for a complete, minimal program that demonstrates the problem you are having. See http://sscce.org for reasons why that is valuable.

Comment: Also, `currentsize` is redundant. Just use `heapVec.size()` when you want to know the current size.

Comment: @Rob: I don't really see how this is minimal... its can be reduced to like 3 lines.

Comment: @Dani, you are right. But it is more nearly minimal than so many programs we see on SO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A vector doesn't grow automatically when you write out of its bounds using subscript operator. To insert to the end of the vector (increasing its size) use this:

```
heapVec.push_back(Node(d));
```

Also don't use `*(new Node(d))`, it won't segfault, but its a memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

Before you access a vector by index you need to allocate space for it

```
 heapVec[currentsize] = *(new Node(d));
```

heapVec.resize(currentsize + 1) should do it. It will ensure that heapVec has at least currentsize + 1 elements and you can access **currentsize**.

One way to avoid this is by modifying your function. As you only are adding to the end of the vector.

```
void Heap::insert(int d) {
    heapVec.push_back( Node(d) );
    currentsize++;
}
```

Please note that you have **vector<Node>** and not **vector<Node*>** so you don't need the **new** call.

Also vector has a **size()** method so you don't need to duplicate it by having your own **currentSize**

Comment: I see what you mean but that's giving me the following:


minheap.cpp:33: error: no matching function for call to ‘Node::Node()’
minheap.cpp:28: note: candidates are: Node::Node(int)
minheap.cpp:8: note:                 Node::Node(const Node&)

Comment: You need a default constructor for anything you put in a `std::vector`.

Comment: @DanielO'Connor: Of course, you need to define a default constructor for Node. Without one, you cannot use a std::vector of Nodes.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're writing outside the range of the vector, which is causing the segmentation fault. You need to either resize the vector to be large enough to contain it, or use `push_back()` to resize it for you.

Second, you have a memory leak - you're creating a `Node` with `new` for no good reason, then copying it into the vector, then losing the pointer and so never deleting the first object.

What you want is

```
heapVec.push_back(Node(d));
```

or in C++11

```
heapVec.emplace_back(d);
```

I would also get rid of your redundant `currentsize` variable and use `heapVec.size()` instead. Also, don't use `new` to create the local heap in `main()`; in general don't use `new` unless you really have to, and when you do, always use smart pointers or very carefully written code to make sure the object is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you got this error because you tried to write out of vector's boundaries. Don't use array syntax (although you're allowed) for operations on vector: in `Heap::insert()` use `heapVec.push_back()`.

Another thing is that you should not bother using `Node` type if it contains only `int` member. Why not just having `vector<int>`?

You can simplify your class further. When you already have `std::vector`, your `currentsize` member is redundant (unnecessary) as `vector::size()` will tell you the current size of it.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong here?

A few different things, including the bug that results in your crash. See my comments below.

```
#include <vector>

// Never, ever, say "using namespace std;" even if (especially if) your textbook says to.
// using namespace std;
using std::vector;

class Node {
private:
    int data;
public:
    // Prefer to define small functions in-class so that they are automatically inline
    // Prefer initialization list to assignment. This is mostly style in your case, but
    // does matter in more complex cases.
    Node(int d) : data(d) {}
    // ~Node();
};

class Heap {
private:
    vector<Node> heapVec;
    // int currentsize;  "currentsize" is redundant, and thus error-prone.
    // heapVec always knows what size it is, so just ask it whenever you need to know.
public:
    // In this trivial example, with currentsize gone, you don't need any constructor.
    // Heap();
    // ~Heap();
    void insert(int);
    void extractMin();
    void reduceKey();
};

void Heap::insert(int d) {
    // This is your crash bug -- std::vector::operator[] doesn't automatically extend
    // the size of the vector (unlike, say, std::map::operator[], which does).
    // Also, your use of "new" here is unconventional, and buggy. You have a memory leak.
    // It is possible to write perfectly useful C++ programs while never invoking "new"
    // directly.
    // heapVec[currentsize] = *(new Node(d));
    // currentsize++;

    // Instead, use std::vector::push_back() or std::vector::insert(), *and* don't call
    // new.
    heapVec.push_back(Node(d));
}


int main() {
    // In this example (and, I bet, in your real-world program), you don't need "new"
    Heap h;
    h.insert(10);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two errors you are doing: The first is the problem you have, and it's that you insert into a specific place in `heapVec` without allocating memory for it. This is solved either by calling `heapVec.reserve(...)` in the `Heap` constructor, or by calling `heapVec.push_back(Node(d))` in `insert`.

The other problem is that when inserting nodes into the vector, you allocate new node and get the contents of it, which will make a copy that is stored in the vector. But you don't store the actual allocated pointer, which means you have a memory leak. You should not allocate in this case.

Comment: `reserve()` doesn't help, except to replace the segmentation fault with more subtle undefined behaviour - it's still illegal to access objects beyond the end of the array. You need to `resize()` before accessing them.